# Изменение размера бэкграунда

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

[image: Скриншот]

Как ограничить размер бэкграунда кнопки?

```
#workbutton  {
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
color: white;
display: flex;
margin-left: 810px;
margin-top: 82px;
background-color: rgba(235, 125, 75, 1);
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 28px 82px 28px 82px;
background-size: 293px 70px 293px 70px;
}
```

Background size просто не работает

Comment: код бы глянуть.

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!